# A stable regular expression or simple library for multi-lingual tokenization?

Tags: regex, nlp, tokenize

We have a product which requires the ability to search, and has primarily been english-focused. As such, tokenization on spaces works relatively well (despite not always being the best idea).

We are recently expanding into the Japanese market and have found a number of complicating factors. Japanese has 2 key gotchas: 1) wordsCanBeStrungTogetherWithoutSpaces
2) Japanese uses different punctuation [symbols](https://www.livinglanguage.com/community/discussion/1339/japanese-punctuation-marks)

We have a workaround for 1, but having a "word" with a few hundred characters causes some complications, so it would be ideal to solve for (2). In the strictest sense I am trying to solve for Japanese, but realistically I would like a way to at least split up sentences regardless of alphabet.  Is there a regex that is good for splitting based on a unicode range? Or will it need to be custom and including every different language?

Quick searching reveals https://unicodelookup.com/#full%20stop/1 it seems that the various "full stop"s are without pattern (as far as I can tell), but there aren't many, and I could build to match those.  My concern is that there are edge cases that I don't know that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the unicode categories are actually well designed for this.  The following regex seems to work fine:

`[\p{L}\p{Nd}]+`
https://regex101.com/r/YEgUQ3/2

And has a simple explanation:

```
\p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language
\p{Nd} matches a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts
```

Where apparently `letter` means strictly not punctuation. And ideographic numbers seem to be just words.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to start out with.
The word is in group 1.

`[^\pL\pN]*([\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|(?![?.!])\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP]))*)(?<!\pP)`

https://regex101.com/r/YEgUQ3/1

Explained

```
 # Unicode

 [^\pL\pN]*                    # Strip non-letters/numbers               
 (                             # (1 start)
      [\pL\pN]                      # First letter/number
      (?:                           # Word body
           [\pL\pN_-]                    # Letter/number or '-'
        |                              # or,
           (?! [?.!] )                   # ( Not Special word ending punctuation, Add more here )
           \pP                           # Punctuation
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP] )             #   if followed by punctuation/letter/number
      )*                            # Do many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?<! \pP )                    # Don't end on a punctuation
```

Comment: This one seems to work well with periods, but doesn't match commas, for example when testing on the text from http://chasen.org/~taku/software/TinySegmenter/

Comment: It seems to miss Japanese characters without spaces (e.g. 、。), by updating the regex  to `[^\pL\pN]*([\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|(?![?.!、。])\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP]))*)(?<!\pP)` it works, but the point was to avoid that

Comment: This is a template. It's something _YOU_ fill out. Don't say this and that doesn't work unless I add this to that. Read the comments in the template, see where it says `( Not Special word ending punctuation, Add more here )` ? This is the place for punctuation in the middle of the word, if you don't want it there, put it in the class. You should be using [RegexFormat 9](http://www.regexformat.com) to write and test this regex, use the UCD database super-tool for Unicode 12. Write custom regex to query Unicode database. This is what I use to write _all_ my regex.

Comment: That makes sense, but it should have been included in the answer then.  In particular part of my original question `Or will it need to be custom and including every different language?` you could have said yes.  I appreciate your answer and that it can be customized, but in the end I found something much more concise/clear that seems to work on all unicode punctuations, and does not require modification for new languages added later.

Comment: Usually, NLP would generally attempt to form words that are bounded by punctuation and whitespace. It is mixed with such rules as hard word stops. These are generally single value punctuation but can be defined as multi-chars as well. When the cruft is torn away from the edges of the words, what remains is a word that can contain certain punctuation. This is just a first level separation of words. These words, their attributes, and their order are preserved for later processing on a macro level to interpret their meaning from lists of phrases and such. Btw,    https://regex101.com/r/FamHo9/1

Comment: NLP often goes further and doesn't try to break up sentences because even splitting at the sentence level loses substantial context information.  In any case it isn't relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm talking about sub-grouping sentences, not breaking them up. Attributes assigned at this low level are crucial in natural language processing on the macro scale imo. It just can't be a search via a fixed list of known phrases, that is way too slow.